# How to make divs fade out one at a time

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, fadeout

I have three divs within a scrollable wrapper. I'd like to make each div fade out when scrolled out of the "wrapper", **one at a time**.

Right now I have all three divs fading out at the same time when I scroll. I spent quite some time trying to figure this out, but still haven't find a solution.

[TEST FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/cr1gcuwz/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".title").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 300);
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Image 1</div>
  <br>
  <div class="title">Image 2</div>
  <br>
  <div class="title">Image 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close, but you'll have to loop through the elements and take into account their position respectively to the top of the page.

Note: usually it's not a good practice to do this kind of thing listening to the scroll event, as it might fire more than necessary, try reading up here: https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/

Note2: I cached the .titles in $titles, for performance reasons.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $titles = $(".title");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $titles.each(function() {
      $(this).css("opacity", 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() - $(this).position().top )/ 300);
    })
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Image 1</div>
  <br>
  <div class="title">Image 2</div>
  <br>
  <div class="title">Image 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you @jonas. If you wouldn't mind, could you please explain this part ? 
`.css("opacity", 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() - $(this).position().top )/ 300)`

Why do we have to subtract the opacity with `$(this).position().top` as well?

Comment: We don't substract the opacity, instead we set the opacity to take into account the position of the scrollbar and the position of the element in the page. If you don't take into account the position of each element there's no way of telling them apart, and they will always fade at the same time (like it did in your example).

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Thank you! @jonas

Answer (score 0):

Try passing function to [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) instead of value, and process it accordingly to the index in the set... but then you have to be sure of order of elements returned by you selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $(".title").css("opacity", function(idx, oldVal) { return (idx+1) - $(window).scrollTop() / 300 });
  })
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Image 1</div>
  <br>
  <div class="title">Image 2</div>
  <br>
  <div class="title">Image 3</div>
</div>
```